# Cassandra. Bloom filter size is > 16GB, reduce the bloom_filter_fp_chance

Tags: cassandra, bloom-filter

After restoring data to Cassandra cluster (1 node) I have error:

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:7] 2016-05-09 08:05:38,621 CassandraDaemon.java:185 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:7,1,main]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Bloom filter size is > 16GB, reduce the bloom_filter_fp_chance
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.obs.OffHeapBitSet.<init>(OffHeapBitSet.java:40) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FilterFactory.createFilter(FilterFactory.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FilterFactory.getFilter(FilterFactory.java:78) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter$IndexWriter.<init>(BigTableWriter.java:470) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter.<init>(BigTableWriter.java:86) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigFormat$WriterFactory.open(BigFormat.java:107) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableWriter.create(SSTableWriter.java:84) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.writers.DefaultCompactionWriter.<init>(DefaultCompactionWriter.java:52) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.getCompactionAwareWriter(CompactionTask.java:237) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:174) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:74) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionCandidate.run(CompactionManager.java:256) ~[apache-cassandra-2.2.5.jar:2.2.5]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
```

Any ideas, how may it be fixed?

Average size of sstable (db file) is 524MB.
Max. size is 167G

```
Bloom filter false positives: 0
Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
Bloom filter space used: 8409389240
Bloom filter off heap memory used: 59948996312
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An approximation formula for bloom filter false positive chance vs space is:

m = n * ln(1/fpc)/ln(2)²

m = size in bytes
n = number of distinct partition keys
fpc = bloom filter false positive chance

see http://www.slideshare.net/doanduyhai/cassandra-data-structures-and-algorithms/57 for the maths details

To have a bloom filter of 16Gb in term of size, you probably have **a lot** of partitions in a single SSTable (and probably very big SSTable).

Can you please:

1. give the avg and max size of your SSTables ?
2. give the bloom filter fp chance configured on the table which is causing issue (use `nodetool cfstats` or `nodetool tablestats`)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've added the information.

Comment: I don't have the bloom_filter_fp_chance, can you get it on the table using `DESCRIBE TABLE xxx` in **cqlsh** ?

Comment: `bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01`

Comment: It looks like you have 1.79*10^9 partitions in the big SSTable (using the maths formula from above). One suggestion is to increase bloom filter fp chance to 0.1. This would reduce the bloom filter size by a factor of 2 e.g. ≈ 8Gb

Comment: Thanks! Error hasn't appeared.